# Status Code 304

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and server-side programming. I am trying to send a GET request to load an image from my blog: http://jsafaiyeh.github.io/img/suw_background.png

```
function imgLoad(url) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  var request = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.responseType='blob';

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      resolve(request.response);
    } else {
      reject(Error('Image did\'t load successfully; error code '+ request.statusText));
    }
  };

  request.onerror= function() {
    reject(Error('There was a network Error'));
  };
  request.send();
});
}

var body = document.querySelector('body');
var myImage = new Image();

imgLoad('http://jsafaiyeh.github.io/img/suw_background.png').then(function response() {
  var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
  myImage.src = imageURL;
  body.appendChild(myImage);
}, function(Error) {
  console.log(Error);
});
```

I get status code 304. However, the image still does not load onto the page. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 2-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL. Using FireFox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong function signature. It should be like this:

```
imgLoad('http://jsafaiyeh.github.io/img/suw_background.png').then(function (response) {
  var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);
  myImage.src = imageURL;
  body.appendChild(myImage);
}, function(Error) {
  console.log(Error);
});
```

[Working demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfb75eav/1/)(at least in Chrome).

Instead of passing named function, called `response` you probably wanted `response` to be in argument list. So, instead of `function response()`, you need `function (response)`. You didn't get error that `response` was undefined, because it actually was declared, but it wasn't expected result from promise, but function.